# jGit using RevWalk to get RevCommit returns nothing

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm newbie on jGit and Git. I'm trying to query the historic of commit of a git repository, but I would like to get only the commit of a specific user. Reading the docs I saw that RevWalk will allow me to add RevFilters in orther to limit the search.

First, I use a Git object and its log method to list the commits, and it works very well. But using RevWalk, nothing happens.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
    FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
    Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File("/home/joan/testGit/testMockito/.git"))
    .readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();

    //This works but I get all the commits
    Git git = new Git(repository);
    Iterable<RevCommit> log = git.log().call();
    for (Iterator<RevCommit> iterator = log.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        RevCommit rev = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(rev.getAuthorIdent().getName());
        System.out.println(rev.getFullMessage());
    }

    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);
    for (Iterator<RevCommit> iterator = walk.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        //It never cames in this block

        RevCommit rev = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(rev.getAuthorIdent().getName());
        System.out.println(rev.getFullMessage());
    }

}
```

Any advice? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add commits to the `RevWalk` by calling`markStart` before iterating over it.

For example to start the `RevWalk` with the current repository's `HEAD` commit:

`walk.markStart(walk.parseCommit(repository.resolve("HEAD")));`

Comment: Thanks Kevin. You're right, I've added the HEAD, and I've got the list of commits. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `LogCommand` from `org.eclipse.jgit.api`?

`Git git = new Git(db);`

`Iterable<RevCommit> log = git.log().call();`

Then you could filter author based on the commits you get back. I also recommend looking at Gitective which is a layer above JGit. You can learn how to implement JGit related things with it: https://github.com/kevinsawicki/gitective/

You could do something like this:

`PersonIdent person = new PersonIdent("Chris", "chris@chris.com");`

`filters.add(new AuthorFilter(person));`

And then you can call `CommitFinder`... with the desired filters...